# How to setup materializecss javascript in Phoenix elixir webapp

Tags: javascript, css, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to use materizecss javascript jquery features, but I'm getting below error message In the browser.

**Error message**: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function`

Any idea how to properly setup javascript? Where to put `<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript --> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>`?

For the example I'm trying to implement, it the `Material Box` for media (https://materializecss.com/media.html),

In my project, I put `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>` and

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.materialboxed').materialbox(); });
</script>
```

at the end of app.html.eex, right before `</body>`

In my .eex.html where I'm showing the image, I showing the image, I used something similar to `img_tag(user.photo_path, class: "materialboxed")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your materialize.min.js setup is correct. It could be other problem.
Try do some to find out by yourself:

1. Check your javascript is ready or not

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log("Javascript is ready")
 $('.materialboxed').materialbox(); 
});
</script>
```

if not, add this before materialize.min.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

2. Check the image has class="materialboxed"

```
<img class="materialboxed" width="650" src="images/sample-1.jpg">
```

3. Error say: .carousel is not a function.
   Recheck function carousel. It should be called like this:

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

and class="carousel" is available

```
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
  </div>
```